# GRUB2 - Windows 10 installer error, multiboot USB

Tags: grub2, removable-storage

I am trying to install a USB memory stick as a (grub2) multiboot and am having trouble booting the Windows installer. Arch Linux doesn't work either, only with KDE neon everything works.

I would prefer the Windows as an "iso" file.
Is there a way to run grub-mkconfig on the USB stick?

**USB-Stick:**

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdb && lsblk -pf /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 7.48 GiB, 8021606400 bytes, 15667200 sectors
Disk model: USB storage device
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0000-UUID-0000

Device      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1    2048   206847   204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  206848 15667166 15460319  7.4G Microsoft basic data

NAME    FSTYPE  LABEL    UUID   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
/dev/sdb
├─/dev/sdb1 vfat   EFI   1111-UUID-1111
└─/dev/sdb2 ntfs   BOOT  2222-UUID-2222
```

I installed the USB stick as described in the [GNU GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)

```
grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt/EFI --boot-directory=/mnt/BOOT --removable
```

I have unzipped the Windows10.iso and copied it on the USB stick.

[image]

**grub.cfg:**

```
    search.fs_uuid 2222-UUID-2222 root hd0,gpt1 
    set prefix=($root)'/grub'
    configfile $prefix/grub.cfg


    menuentry 'Windows 10' --class win10 {
        search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 2222-UUID-2222
        chainloader (${root})/win10/bootmgr.efi
    }

    menuentry "KDE neon GNU/Linux" ---calss neon {
        set isofile="/iso/KDEneon.iso"
        loopback loop (${root})$isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
    }
```

[image: Boot error]

--- EDIT ---

I moved the contents of the "win10" folder to "/" and now the Windows installer boots with this strings:

```
search.fs_uuid 2222-UUID-2222 root hd0,gpt1 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg


menuentry 'Windows 10' {
    chainloader (${root})/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try changing `chainloader (${root})/win10/bootmgr.efi` to `chainloader  (${root})/win10/efi/boot/bootx64.efi`.

Comment: I moved the contents of the "win10" folder to "/" and now the windows installer boots beautifully with the strings you gave. Thanks!
Can you help me with the "ArchLinux.iso"? I can't get it to boot either.

Comment: Is there a way to boot the Windows10.iso?